# Slick slider error: TypeError: o[i].slick is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make it so that when the search button is pressed it will clear the previous search results from the screen and create the new search results. However when I do this, I get a slick slider error and all my items line up vertically. I'm not exactly sure if the thing I'm trying to do is possible to do with slick slider because I am essentially creating the `search-slider` div. When I don't remove() my `search-slider`div, the previous results will be loaded next to the old results but they will be rendered by slick slider. I'm not sure where I should go from here.

FYI, the snippet will not run on here. I made it for ease of looking at the code.
If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```js
$(function() {


      $('#search').click(function() {
            var nameVal = $('#shouhinName').val();
            var makerVal = $('#makerName').val();
            var categoryVal = $('#selectText').val();
            var sliderVal = $('#hideme').val();

            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "shelf/test",
                  data: {


                    shouhinName: nameVal,
                    makerName: makerVal,
                    selectText: categoryVal,
                    best: sliderVal

                  },
                  success: function hi(j_data) {




                      alert(j_data.url);
                      // create a new div element 
                      //const images = j_data;
                      //   console.log(imagePath);
                      /*   for (const image of imagePath) {

                              const img = document.createElement("img");
                              if (image.slice(0, 5) == "shelf") {
                                    img.src = `/check/assets/img/${image}`;
                              } else {
                                    img.src = '/check/assets/img/noimage.png';
                              }

                              img.classList.add("new");
                              var div = document.createElement("div");
                              div.id = `${image}`
                              div.classList.add("image");
                              linebreak = document.createElement("br");

                              // div.classList.add("column");
                              document.getElementById('search-slider').appendChild(div);

                              // document.getElementById('rows').appendChild(div);
                              //img.setAttribute("style", "text-align: center;"); 
                              // document.body.appendChild(img);

                              document.getElementById(image).appendChild(img);


                        } */

                      console.log(j_data);
                      //  console.log(images);

                      let index = 0;
                      const display = "table"; // or "grid" if horizontal, but this migh depend where you place the rest of the code, cause i added the style to the body
                      const x = 0;
                      const y = 0;
                      document.body.style.display = display;
                      $('#search-slider').remove();
                      //  function createHTML() {
                      //  console.log("E: Execute & R: Request & I: Informative");
                      //loop to go true all images

                      const search = document.createElement("div");
                      search.id = 'search-slider';
                      search.className = "search-items";
                      console.log(search.id);
                      document.getElementById("divbox").appendChild(search);
                      for (const image of j_data.url) {
                        // console.log();
                        //each image will correspond to a canvas element
                        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



                        //each canvas element will has is own properties (in this case all the same)
                        canvas.id = "option" + [index];
                        var canId = canvas.id;
                        var tooltip = j_data.tooltip;

                        //   console.log(tooltip[index]);
                        // tooltip is the array
                        // var tooltipSel = document.getElementById(canId);

                        /* canvas.height = images.height;
                        canvas.width = images.width; */
                        // canvas.setAttribute('heigth', '0');
                        canvas.setAttribute('width', '75px');
                        canvas.setAttribute('padding-top', '56.25%');
                        canvas.setAttribute('object-fit', 'contain');
                        canvas.setAttribute('data-html', 'true');
                        // canvas.title = "hi";
                        // console.log('#'+ canvas.id);

                        var div = document.createElement("div");
                        div.setAttribute('data-html', 'true');
                        div.id = j_data.itemid[index]; //image.slice(26, 34);
                        // $('#'+div.id).remove();
                        /* var itemID = div.id;
                        var itemidArray = [];
                        itemidArray = itemID; */
                        //   console.log(itemidArray);

                        console.log(div.id);
                        //   canvas.style.padding = "10px";
                        // canvas.classList.add("suiteiCanvas");
                        //function to get the corresponded image of that particular canvas element
                        drawImages(canvas);
                        //add an event listener for when a user click on the particular canvas

                        canvas.addEventListener("click", optionClicke, false);

                        //all html part was handle we can append it to the body
                        // document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                        //console.log(image);
                        var text = j_data.tooltip[index];
                        /* div.title = "";
                        $('#' + div.id).data('powertip', function() {
                              return div.title = tooltip[index];
                        }); */
                        div.title = text;
                        document.getElementById('search-slider').appendChild(div);
                        document.getElementById(div.id).appendChild(canvas);
                        //  $(div.id).prepend(text);
                        index++;
                      }
                      //  }

                      //  console.log(itemidArray);

                      function drawImages(canvas) {
                        //we need to use the getContext canvas function to draw anything inside the canvas element
                        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        const background = new Image();

                        // for text

                        //This is needed because if the drawImage is called from a different place that the createHTML function
                        //index value will not be at 0 and it will for sure with an heigher id that the one expected
                        //so we are using regex to remove all letters from the canvas.id and get the number to use it later
                        index = canvas.id.replace(/\D/g, "");

                        //console.log('E: Drawing image ' + index + ' on canvas ' + canvas.id);

                        //get the image url using the index to get the corresponded image
                        // background.src = images.url[index];
                        if (j_data.url[index] !== '/check/assets/img/noimage.png') {
                          background.src = "/check/assets/img/" + j_data.url[index];
                        } else {
                          background.src = '/check/assets/img/noimage.png'
                        }


                        //no idea why but to place the image, we need to use the onload event
                        //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage
                        background.onload = function() {

                          ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        };
                        /* background.onerror = function() {
                              const text = "インバ ど";
                              ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0 + 10 * 1);
                        }; */
                      }

                      function drawX(canvas, item) {
                        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                        //   console.log("E: Placing X on canvas " + canvas.id);

                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(40, 75, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
                        ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.stroke();
                        console.log(item);
                        hdnName.value = item;

                      }

                      /*  function fillTextLine(canvas, x, y) {
                             var text = "インバ ど";
                             const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                             var textList = text.split("　");
                             var lineHeight = ctx.measureText("あ").width;
                             textList.forEach(function(text, i) {
                                   ctx.fillText(text, x, y + lineHeight * i);
                             });
                       } */

                      function clear(canvas) {
                        //   console.log("E: clearing canvas " + canvas.id);

                        canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                        drawImages(canvas);


                      }

                      function optionClicke(e) {
                        log = true;
                        const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
                        var hdnName = document.getElementById("sendServ");
                        let index = 0;


                        for (const option of canvas) {
                          if (log)
                            //  console.log("I: User clicked at option " + e.target.id + ":" + option.id);
                            log = false;
                          if (e.target.id === option.id) {
                            // console.log("R: Drawing request at canvas " + option.id);
                            // console.log(j_data.itemid[index]);
                            const item = j_data.itemid[index];
                            console.log('draw' + item);
                            console.log(index);
                            drawX(option, item);

                          } else {
                            //   console.log("R: Clearing request at canvas " + option.id);
                            clear(option);
                            //console.log('clear'+item);
                          }
                          index++;
                        }

                      }

$('.search-items').slick('unslick').slick('reinit');
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search-items').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
    infinite: false, //true
    slidesToShow: 8,
    slidesToScroll: 8,
    arrows: true,
    centerMode: false,
    width: 200,
    prevArrow: $('.prev'),
    nextArrow: $('.next')
  });
});





//  console.log(j_data);
// need to do my image processing in here 
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log("post error");
    console.log(error);
    alert(error);
  },
  complete: function(xhr, status) {
    console.log("fin");
  },
});
});
});
```

```css
.search-items{
  max-width: 1800px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="search-items" id="search-slider">
                  


                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed

```
 let index = 0;
 const display = "table"; // or "grid" if horizontal, but this migh depend where you place the rest of the code, cause i added the style to the body
 const x = 0;
 const y = 0;
 document.body.style.display = display;
 $('#search-slider').remove();
 //  function createHTML() {
 //  console.log("E: Execute & R: Request & I: Informative");
 //loop to go true all images

 const search = document.createElement("div");
 search.id = 'search-slider';
 search.className = "search-items";
 console.log(search.id);
 document.getElementById("divbox").appendChild(search);
```

and reverted my code by to where the items were lining up to each other.

I needed to add $('.search-items').slick('slickRemove', 0);

So I made a for loop to count my item id's before my loop that went over my images.

```
 for (const id of j_data.itemid) {


   $('.search-items').slick('slickRemove', 0);

 }
```

This removed the first search result every time I pressed my search button.

Hopefully this helps someone else.